# Access 2016 VBA: How can I use a control name in a formula?

Tags: ms-access, vba

In my Access 2016 report I have 10 controls named txt1 to txt10 and I want to populate them from records in a table.  Is there any way to increment the control name in my loop based on my counter?

Something like this.  Obviously Me.txt(counter) is not an array but the best representation I can give for what I want to do.

```
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim counter as integer

Set db=CurrentDatabase
Set rs=db.OpenRecordSet("SELECT * FROM table WHERE variable = " & something)

If Not rs.EOF Then
    rs.MoveFirst
    counter = 1
    Do Until rs.EOF
        Me.txt(counter) = rs.Fields("field1")
        counter = counter + 1
        rs.MoveNext
    Loop
End If
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following:

```
Me("txt" & counter) = rs.Fields("field1")
```